# How to convert str date time to datetime obj

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I get string datetime from email

```
print(email_message['Date'])
```

It looks like

```
Fri, 31 Jan 2020 09:59:34 +0000 (UTC)
```

And then I try to convert it to datetime obj

```
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(email_message['Date'], '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z %Z')
```

and see an Error message

```
ValueError: time data 'Fri, 31 Jan 2020 09:59:34 +0000 (UTC)' does not match format '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z %Z'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to take the `()` around timezone into account.

```
datetime.strptime(email_message['Date'], "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z (%Z)")
```